# Groups of chains with positional arguments in partial tasks using Celery

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, celery, celery-task

I am writing an application which will execute a group of several synchronous chains of tasks asynchronously.

In other words, I might have the pipeline `foo(a,b,c) -> boo(a,b,c)` for some list of `bs`.

My understanding is to create a chain of `foo(a,b,c) | boo(a,b,c)` for each b in this list. These chains will then form a celery group, which can be applied asynchronously.

My code to do this is below:

> ## my_app.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import functools
import time

from celery import chain, group, Celery
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)

app = Celery("my_app", broker='redis://localhost:6379/0', backend='redis://localhost:6379/0')

@app.task
def foo(a, b, c):
    logger.info("foo from {0}!".format(b))
    return b

@app.task
def boo(a, b, c):
    logger.info("boo from {0}!".format(b))
    return b

def break_up_tasks(tasks):
    try:
        first_task, *remaining_tasks = tasks
    except ValueError as e:
        first_task, remaining_tasks = [], []
    return first_task, remaining_tasks

def do_tasks(a, bs, c, opts):
    tasks = [foo, boo]

    # There should be an option for each task
    if len(opts) != len(tasks):
        raise ValueError("There should be {0} provided options".format(len(tasks)))

    # Create a list of tasks that should be included per the list of options' boolean values
    tasks = [task for opt, task in zip(opts, tasks) if opt]

    first_task, remaining_tasks = break_up_tasks(tasks)

    # If there are no tasks, we're done.
    if not first_task: return

    chains = (
        functools.reduce(
            # `a` should be provided by `apply_async`'s `args` kwarg
            # `b` should be provided by previous partials in chain
            lambda x, y: x | y.s(c),
            remaining_tasks, first_task.s(a, b, c)
        ) for b in bs
    )

    g = group(*chains)
    res = g.apply_async(args=(a,), queue="default")
    print("Applied async... waiting for termination.")

    total_tasks = len(tasks)

    while not res.ready():
        print("Waiting... {0}/{1} tasks complete".format(res.completed_count(), total_tasks))
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = "whatever"
    bs = ["hello", "world"]
    c = "baz"

    opts = [
        # do "foo"
        True,
        # do "boo"
        True
    ]

    do_tasks(a, bs, c, opts)
```

> ## Running celery

```
celery worker -A my_app -l info -c 5 -Q default
```

What I'm finding, though, is that when I run the above, my server client runs an infinite loop because `boo` is missing an argument:

> `TypeError: boo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'c'`

My understanding is that `apply_async` will provide the `args` kwarg to each chain and that previous links in the chain will provide their return value to subsequent links.

Why is `boo` not receiving the arguments properly? I'm sure these tasks aren't well-written as this is my first foray into Celery. If you have other suggestions, I'm happy to entertain them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After debugging your code ( I'm new to Celery too! :) ) I've learned that each chained function will get the first argument replaced by the result of the previous chained function call - so with that said I believe the solution to your problem is to add one missing argument ( 2nd one ) to the y.s in the reduce:

```
chains = (
    functools.reduce(
        # `a` should be provided by `apply_async`'s `args` kwarg
        # `b` should be provided by previous partials in chain
        lambda x, y: x | y.s(b,c), # <- here is the 'new guy'
        remaining_tasks, first_task.s(a, b, c)
    ) for b in bs
)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sure, but supplying `args` to `Group.apply_async` does the same thing. Why doesn't that work?

Comment: I believe that arguments from apply_async functions are applied to the first function in the chain - the next one will receive only the first argument from it's parent.

Comment: Which is kind of explained here - http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#linking-callbacks-errbacks - it is hard to find a documentation for how this function works on chains.